# javascript convert hostname URL into full URL

Tags: javascript, url, base-url

I want to convert a domain name url (e.g : `discord.com`, `google.com` into a full URL (e.g : `https://discord.com/`, `https://www.google.com/`).
The problem is that I cannot know in advance if it will be `http` or `https`.

I can try to do something like this -

```js
try {
    url = 'https://' + url;
} catch {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}
```

but something inside me tells me it's not the correct way to do it (also it does not work)

Comment: If you don't know in advance your endpoint. Then problem is not in contracting URL, but problem in connection. You would need to construct both http and https, then try to connect one, catch the problem and try the second connection attempt.

Comment: is it how browsers works in general ?

Comment: How browsers do that depends on many factors, including but not limited to web server response, protocol in use, browser implementation.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is HTTP but more secure, usually HTTPS sites will upgrade your connection to HTTPS automatically if they support it. The most simple way to convert hostnames is to add HTTP:// and the website will do the rest.

Comment: yes if the website knows how to redirect requests, but the websites I'm targeting are in http and doesn't automatically redirect to https

Comment: HTTPS is almost identical to HTTP; it's slightly safer to use HTTPS but in the end, it doesn't make much difference. I'd suggest that you just use HTTP for every site and not deal with automatically detecting and using HTTPS.